# Unable to delete Azure Resource Group

Tags: azure-resource-manager, azure-aks, azure-databricks, azure-log-analytics, azure-storage-account

I'm trying to delete Ra esource Group or the resources in that group.

- Databricks got deleted half-way is now in a failed state and can't be removed
- A storage account can't be deleted because of an other resource requiring exclusive access
- The Private Endpoint on the Storage Account can't be deleted, because there is no changes possible on the Storage Account - I'm owner on Subscription level
- The AKS namespace returns an 'internal server error'
- The Log Analytics workspace I can't delete because a SQL solution can be deleted 'ajaxExtended call failed'

Tried using CLI, PowerShell, checked for Locks, re-registered providers, tried moving resources ....

Comment: Just to many thinks failing at the same time , I could suggest to work with Microsoft support and see if they can provide any more insight .

Comment: Thanks, but I don't have a support contract and quite frankly I don't see why I should pay Microsoft to help me delete services I no longer need. I also have other irregularities in this subscription. Quite scary actually.

Comment: @FelixBodmer Too many failures can make it difficult to troubleshoot. Start with a resource with least/no dependencies. Try updating/correcting failed resource properties manually with PS/CLI and check if that helps when re-triggering deletes.

Comment: Tried that already, but didn't work.